# Possible sum of roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Let P(x) be a monic cubic polynomial with real roots such that P(0) = 0 and
> P(1) = 1. If S is the sum of the roots of P(x), how many integer values cannot be
> attained by S? *Source: CMC Y2 10B*

From the problem statement, $P(x)=x(x-r)(x-s)$, so using $P(1)=1$, we get $rs=r+s$. After isolating one of the variables, say $r$, we have $r=\frac{s}{s-1}$, and thus $r+s=\frac{s^2}{s-1}.$ But then there are only two pairs of integer solutions, since only $2$ works for $s$, and the answer choices are $0,1,3,4,6.$

What did I misinterpret, and any hints or solutions as to how to go on?

Comment: Nothing says the roots have to be integers. We are only concerned with whether the _sum_ is an integer. Note that it is given that there are infinitely many integers the sum could be.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Let $P(x)=x(x-1)(x-r)+x=x^3-(r+1)x^2+(r+1)x$

$\implies S=r+1$

We need $$(r+1)^2-4(r+1)\ge0$$

$$\iff (r+1)(r-3)\ge0$$

$\implies$ either $r\ge3$ or $r\le-1$